# How to set primary key in decoupled datalayer

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

I'd like to decouple BL from DAL. Especially i want to have primary key protected (I don't want my business users to modify Item.Id).

In my DataLayer (let's imagine it is a simple sql table with autogenerated primary key) I try to insert item and update item.Id.
Of course I can't because it is protected property.

Is there a way to do this without using a reflection?
(I mean maybe my architecture is wrong...)

BusinessLayer:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<Item>
{
    void Insert(Item item);

    //and other CRUD operations
}
```

DataLayer (using EntityFramework with sqlserver):

```
public class EfRepository : IRepository<Item>
{
    EfContext ctx;     
    public void Insert(Item item)
    {      
        //EfContext uses its ItemEntity, so I have to map Item to EntityItem
        var mapped = AutoMapper.Map<Item, EntityItem>(item);
        ctx.Items.Add(mapped); 
        //after this operation EF will set primary key to mapped object
        //and now I need to set this to primary key to my business
        //domain object.
        item.Id = ?? // can't set protected property!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: if you are using SQL server then you can set it on Db itself no need to do anything more

Comment: create table test 
(
  Id int Identity(1,1) primary key ,
  Name varchar(100)
)

Comment: this will create a table name test and set Id autoincrement plus primary key

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I try to separate my business logic from data layer. What database I'm using should not be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect your logic against accidental modifications `Id` you can use "property injection pattern":

```
public class Item
{
    public Item() 
    { 
        _id = -1; 
    }

    public int Id 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _id; 
        }

        set
        {
             if (_id != -1)
             {
                 throw new OperationException("Item.Id has already been set");
             }

             _id = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It requires changing Item.Id to public, but should work.

Comment: Yes... but your intention was _avoid business users to modify Item.Id_, not?  It is quite easy solution. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should accomplish this in the database. How you do this depends on which database you are using.

If you need to set some other ID specifically through code, I would suggest adding another property for that specifically and letting your database still generate the primary key.

For example, you can use Dapper to call a stored procedure that will do the insertion (and whatever key generation) you want.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments

if you are using SQL server then you can set it on Db itself no need to do anything more

```
 create table test 
(
 Id int Identity(1,1) primary key ,
   Name varchar(100)
  )
```

Also you can alter existing int column to be identity as well . using alter table sql command

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using an auto-generated sequential integer for primary key, you are going to have several issues with protecting the data. You have to pass the key from server to client, so when the user updates the data, you can find the associated record. A malicious user can change the PK using different tools and access different records simply by changing the value of the primary key, because it is easy to guess the value of PK for other records. Of course you know all of this.

The industry standard solution for this problem is using a key that is not easy to guess (not a sequential integer value). If you are using SQL Server as the database, you can add a new column to you table with type defined as GUID and use it as PK. GUID value will be automatically assigned by server, it is not sequential and it is very difficult to guess other values. I am not familiar with other DB engines, but in short, the solution is using GUID.

Here is how to you declare the column and add rows in the table (copied from this MSDN article: [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx](http://Using%20Uniqueidentifier) )

```
CREATE TABLE MyUniqueTable
   (UniqueColumn   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      DEFAULT NEWID(),
   Characters      VARCHAR(10) )
GO
INSERT INTO MyUniqueTable(Characters) VALUES ('abc')
INSERT INTO MyUniqueTable VALUES (NEWID(), 'def')
```

Comment: I thought about GUID but I try to design my application so that a user in business logic can only read primary key (maybe this is wrong design). Primary key should only be set in data layer.

Comment: GUID can be the primary key. There is no rule saying that PK has to be defined as an integer. A primary key is a key that uniquely identifies each record. Since GUID is unique, it can be used as the primary key too